# What is said exactly in the video?

Tags: pronunciation, listening

I watched a funny video [Mufasa x Hypeman spreading good vibes around the world- Bag Raiders- Shooting Stars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5CZz4rrRY8) but I couldn't understand what exactly was said in the 3-rd sentence (2-d second of the video).

> Hey Mufasa!
>
> Ugh?
>
> **??? spread your vibes?**
>
> Spread them where?

Does anyone have a clue what was said here - "??? spread your vibes" exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hey Mufasa!
>
> Huh?
>
> Where you spread your vibes?
>
> Spread them where?

Note that Standard (British) English would grammatically require the sentence to be "Where *do* you spread your vibes?", but dropping the "do" is idiomatic in many global English dialects.

Also, as a side note, "ugh" is idiomatically used to transcribe a noise of disgust, which doesn't fit Mufasa's reaction here, so I've transcribed it "huh?" instead, which is more typical for this context.

Answer (score 0):

Huh?

Ready to spread your vibes?

Spread them where?